# Bootstrap Grid has offset second row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to lay this page here:
http://marcmurray.net/Napier_Test/index.html

Out something more like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4B6r.png

I have tried a few different methods but can't seem to get it. Adding margins between the grid items pushes them out further, and I'd rather not have to nudge the entire row across to get rid of the offset as I think that would be a hacky way to fix something I am more than likely doing wrong. 
Any ideas?

Bootply here(minus the JQuery):
http://www.bootply.com/OzQAQwr9N1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a little formatting on the HTML and CSS:

1. Remove the extra col-lg-12 div which is between row and .item divs
2. Change the .item div so that it's child of a col-sm-4
3. Remove the unnecessary styles from .item.

Maybe add margin-top to .item to get little spacing there.

Like this: http://www.bootply.com/MKWJEnW3ZD

Comment: The unnecessary styles were from trying to cram the divs into place, started adding some ridiculous stuff! That worked perfectly, thanks a million!